# MySQL select unique record from a joint table that have duplicated referencing entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

How do you display everything from a table that do not currently match a result in the second table.

Eg: I want to display each name in (Table A) who do not currently have a record for type 1. Note that 'Ken' currently have two log entry. One for each type 1 and type 2. The result should display just John and Genius

**Table A** - Name

```
+-----+--------+
| nid |  name  |
+-----+--------+
|   1 |    ken |
|   2 |   john |
|   3 | genius |
+-----+--------+
```

**Table B** - Log (each name may have multiple entry)

```
+------+-----+
| type | nid |
+------+-----+
|    1 |   1 |
|    2 |   1 |
|    2 |   2 |
+------+-----+
```

**Expected result**

```
| nid |  name  |
+-----+--------+
|   2 |   john |
|   3 | genius |
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is sort of the records with type='1' in subquery

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLEA WHERE NID NOT IN (SELECT NID FROM TABLEB WHERE TYPE='1')
```

Comment: Probably solved my problem. Checking on it. I was not familiar with comparing column with NOT IN function :D

Comment: @Ken: Hope this helps you.This is the easiest way to start of with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nid, name from tableA 
 inner join tableB on tableA.nid = tableB.nid
 where nid > 1
```

Comment: This looks like it'd select every user other than the one where `nid = 1`, if they have *any* records in table B.  It doesn't filter by type.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/149d2/1)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB b WHERE a.nid = b.nid AND b.type = 1)
```

Comment: Would `NOT EXIST` work better than `NOT IN`? And is there any reason why you need to match values from both table? Seems like @VJHil was just suggesting to pull `NID` that are using `TYPE 1` then subsequently select from `TABLE A` where those `NID` do not exist.

Comment: @Ken: This is the exact equivalent to VJHil's IN clause. The idea of EXISTS is: for every record in TableA check if an appropriate record in TableB exists. The idea of IN is: Get all appropriate IDs from TableB, then select only records from TableA that match. In both cases you compare TableA.nid with TableB.nid. In MySQL the EXISTS clause is often faster than the IN clause. Moreover the IN clause only works with one column (nid in this example) in MySQL. But I agree, I too usually prefer the IN clause for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a left join...

```
SELECT a.nid, a.name
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.nid = b.nid AND b.type = 1
WHERE b.nid IS NULL
```

Basically, if the query can't find a record in table B that satisfies the join condition, it'll join a row of all nulls.

Comment: Seem to be working as well but @VJHil method seem cleaner. Would this be more efficient in any way?

Comment: @Ken: Not sure.  A decent DBMS should treat both pretty much the same.  I've seen MySQL be less than decent in this regard, but for a query this simple, it ought to know to run the sub-select once.  An `EXPLAIN` on each query might be enlightening.